# Cartoon about three kids that are trained by an old lady to fight

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I watched this cartoon a long time ago but can't remember its name. I remember one specific episode where the antagonist messes with the past, so the kids aren't raised by the old lady and instead she teaches one kid who wears a mascot costume and uses a spinning sign.

I'm pretty sure two of the kids were boys and one girl.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?  ("A long time ago" isn't specific enough; what year?)  What was the animation style?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?  Was there a single antagonist or a different antagonist every episode?  How many episodes did you watch?

Comment: While the concept of kids fighting doesn't necessarily preclude sci fi or fantasy, it's not a given. Is there anything about the show that suggests that it was in either of these genres?

Comment: I know it’s not correct, but the first thing that popped into my mind was the Rise of Gru Minions movie that just came out. 3 minion kids being taught by an old lady how to fight.

Comment: In the early 2000s pretty sure there was a singular antagonist in the animation from what I remember was similar to Jackie chan's adventures and for some reason I specifically remember fortune cookies being involved I think I was really young at the time so my memory ain't the best.